# Iptables: Drop all incoming IP4 traffic on a port

Tags: networking, iptables, ipv6, ipv4

I want to drop ALL the ipv4 traffic on a certain port and only allow ipv6 traffic with iptables. Is it possible? is so, how?

Comment: You should be setting your chain policies to default to drop.  So all you have to do is not add rule to permit traffic.  If you already have a complex rule set, then you might need to tell us what rules you currently have, so we can tell you what to add, and where.

Comment: When you say port, do you mean an ethernet port, or a protocol port (please specify TCP or UDP)

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this directly with just iptables as it only controls ipv4. To interact with netfilter for ipv6 you have to use the [ip6tables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip6tables) command.  To block the IPv4 port just use iptables as you would normally e,g,

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

To open the IPv6 port use [ip6tables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip6tables) e.g.

```
ip6tables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the best way to block *all* IPv4 traffic is not to have an IPv4 address on the port; I'm not sure why `iptables` would be needed to drop all IPv4 traffic.

Comment: You could conceivably want to do something like this for testing purposes.

Comment: Or you want to still be able to ssh access the server because your personal network only supports ipv4